# Facebook multiple og:image tags - Which is Default?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

My web site specifies multiple og:image tags, and I'd like to control which one is the default. Does it have something to do with the order in which they're specified?

Right now the images are appearing in the link post selector in the order #3, #1, #2 (#3 being the default), which seems quite unusual.

Thanks for any insights you might have.

Comment: You shouldn't really be defining multiple `og:image` tags. What are you trying to achieve by having >1?

Comment: Is it that unusual? When a user shares the link, it will allow them to choose which image is displayed on their feed. That was my understanding, anyway.

Comment: imho it´s not unusual to define multiply images in the og tags, so the user can choose when he shares. it all depends on the type of content. if it´s a product page for example, then may want to use one specific high quality image of that product so people can recognize it easier. that being said, i don´t know how to define the default image, i always thought that the first one that gets defined is the default one...

Comment: og defines og:image as an Array

Comment: Pinterest defines that you can have multiple og:image tags https://developers.pinterest.com/rich_pins_article/ the likely reason (in my case) that I'd want them is to have different sized/ratio images that will look better in different sites e.g. one for Facebook, another for Twitter and another for Pinterest.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I was curious, so I scoured around trying to find an answer to the "default image" question. This was literally the only link I could find where any research had been done on the matter, where they suggest that higher-res images will receive top priority:

[How to set priority order to Open Graph images for links that are inserted in comments. (Not sharing or wall posts.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365156/how-to-set-priority-order-to-open-graph-images-for-links-that-are-inserted-in-co/12726245#12726245)

However, based on that example, FB might just be picking the last og:image tag on the list. A previous SO answer came to a similar conclusion:

[Facebook sharer.php, how to have multiple og:image tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944268/facebook-sharer-php-how-to-have-multiple-ogimage-tags/5568462#5568462)

I apologize if I answered your question with more questions, but maybe this will give you a good lead, at least. If you add more tags and FB consistently picks the last one, you'll hopefully have your solution. :)

Comment: Based on some experimentation today, I'm getting the same results. Regardless of order, Facebook defaulted to the largest (in pixels) image. I haven't tested whether it's overall area or width or height, but it's at least a clue.

This came up for me because I'm using a WordPress plugin (WordPress SEO by Yoast) that adds all post images as og:image tags, regardless of size. Only images greater than 200x200 are accepted as options by FB, but the largest one proved to be the default.

Answer (score 11):

From [the Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me/#array):

> **Arrays**
>
> If a tag can have multiple values, just put multiple versions of the same `<meta>` tag on your page. The first tag (from top to bottom) is given preference during conflicts.
>
> `<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/rock.jpg" />`
>
> `<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/rock2.jpg" />`

When I test this in the [Facebook Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/), I only see the first image previewed. But when I begin a share of my URL on Facebook itself, I see the first image previewed along with the left/right buttons for choosing the second image, as below:

[image: Facebook left/right image share buttons.]

Comment: I have the same problem. Is there a some way to facebook to use only the one seen in Facebook Sharing Debugger?

Answer (score 3):

Here's what works for me. In the header of your page, insert this code

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://yourdomain.com/yourimage.png" />
```

This gives the image I choose priority. It should be one of the highest resolution photos on your page.

Then, force Facebook to clear it's cache with [this](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/). This debugger tool will also show you which image Facebook is favouring.

Comment: Thank you for the debugger link. It's so useful to be able to clear that image, otherwise it's super sticky!