# Multiple open graph tags, which one is prioritized?

Tags: html, facebook, metadata, facebook-opengraph, reddit

I've seen various SO threads about FB open graph image tags such as this: [Facebook multiple og:image tags - Which is Default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424780/facebook-multiple-ogimage-tags-which-is-default)

These threads are 2.5 years old so I'm wondering if the rules have been updated. Also, the accepted answer of the highest resolution image being the one displayed seems imperfect. What if the images aren't the same? For example, how to have one image for the homepage and then a different one on AJAX loaded pages?

As these rules are used by FB, Reddit and many high-traffic sites obviously this information is very valuable. Thanks!

Comment: http://ogp.me/ – which Facebook refers to itself in their documentation IIRC – says, _“If a tag can have multiple values, just put multiple versions of the same <meta> tag on your page. The first tag (from top to bottom) is given preference during conflicts.”_ … not sure though FB honors that when it comes to images, they might rather pick which size or aspect ratio they think displays best in newsfeed/timeline.

Comment: _“For example, how to have one image for the homepage and then a different one on AJAX loaded pages?”_ – that is a completely different matter. Open Graph objects are identified by their URL – if you want to share content that you load via AJAX, make sure that content has its own unique URL that Facebook’s scraper can request the OG meta data from.

Answer (score 0):

Since reddit is open-source, you can look at see what its behavior is.

The place you want to look is [`_find_thumbnail_image()`](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/r2/lib/media.py#L555).  Right now, this is the code that pertains to Open Graph:

```
    # Allow the content author to specify the thumbnail using the Open
    # Graph protocol: http://ogp.me/
    og_image = (soup.find('meta', property='og:image') or
                soup.find('meta', attrs={'name': 'og:image'}))
    if og_image and og_image['content']:
        return og_image['content'], None
    og_image = (soup.find('meta', property='og:image:url') or
                soup.find('meta', attrs={'name': 'og:image:url'}))
    if og_image and og_image['content']:
        return og_image['content'], None
```

So, it'll use whatever [Beautiful Soup's `find()` method returns](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find), which should be the first matching tag.