# How can I create a variable Meta property og:image for multiple pages?

Tags: image, properties, meta

Here's the code i'm trying to get work which should explain what I'm trying to do.

```
<script>document.write('<meta property="og:image" content="' + location.pathname.replace(/\.html$/, '.jpg') + '">')</script>
```

Just trying to edit meta property create an image for the og:image that has the same name of the .html file. So far no luck

Answer (score 0):

Facebook thumbnail images are generated through something like a search engine web-crawler. It follows links and fetches the needed data from the page. But clients like web crawlers and fb-share only see your HTML, not all the resources on a page - namely client-side scripts like javascript & jQuery. That means your script will not be run, and thus the meta tag not created. Instead try a PHP server side implementation like:

```
http://mylink.com/?ogimage_id=7 calls
<meta property="og:image" content= <?php $path_to_image_dir . "/" $_GET['ogimage_id']
```

See my answer here [Facebook sharer.php, how to have multiple og:image tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944268/facebook-sharer-php-how-to-have-multiple-ogimage-tags)