# Facebook choosing same image in multiple og:image tag

Tags: drupal-7, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I have read the following:

[Facebook multiple og:image tags - Which is Default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424780/facebook-multiple-ogimage-tags-which-is-default)

[Facebook sharer.php, how to have multiple og:image tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944268/facebook-sharer-php-how-to-have-multiple-ogimage-tags)

When multiple `og:image` tags are present the choosing order is *speculated* as follows:

- Last image is the one selected
- Image with the most resolution is selected

**Problem**

A **Drupal** site that shares articles that sometimes have main images in the body. In the same page there are other images that are **not** related to the article but to relative content (they are thumbnails of other articles). I don't want Facebook to pick those images up, so I set a **default** share image that portrays the logo of the site, in case the article has no main image.

Tags in `head` are as follows:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="/sites/default/files/article_main_image.jpg">
<meta property="og:image" content="/sites/default/files/SITE_DEFAULT_image.jpg">
```

**Up until last friday (August 4th 2017)** it was working perfect. If the article had an image then it shared the intended image, if it didn't then it shared the default image with the site's logo on it.

Then came Saturday...and low and behold, all the auto shares in Facebook **only** show the default site image. Facebook is completely ignoring the article's main image. I have no idea why.

**Things I have tried (to no avail)**

- Change order of `og:image` tag so that main article is last one always
- Change size of default image to be lowest possible, 200x200 pixels (original order of apperance)
- Change size of default image to be lowest possible and make it appear first so that main article image is last

I have no idea what else to do to make it work again. Worst of all I don't know how to explain why it is no longer working. It's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out what was happening. For the field in Drupal I did not have a single value, but rather a comma separated list of values, because the image could come from different fields.

Turns out that when the fields described in the input were empty or had no value, the site's domain was printed out. I figure Facebook saw the home link and took whatever image they wanted from it.

Solution?

Only have the image value in that field, period.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge, when there are multiple `og:image` tags, Facebook picks the image with better resolution.

Look at below answer for details.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12726245/3086531

I guess, in your case, Your site's default image has higher resolution than your article image.

One workaround you can try, is to use a php function to populate meta tags and add them to header. You can have all your logic inside it.

Comment: I thought this might be it, but no dice. I changed the image resolution of the default image to nothing. It still took it up.